# Need help in writing Time Interval gap (say 5 mins ie: 10:05 - 10:10) in select statement in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I was asked to get data from SQL Server, for a time interval of 5 minutes for a particular hour, which is the peak hour of publishing data on that day. I managed to get that peak hour for a particular day in a separate query.

I used the following query to get the data for 5mins interval

```
select  
    count(pbcnt) as county, --MIN(pubpeakhr) ,
    cast(MIN(DATEPART(HOUR,pubpeakhr)) as varchar) + ':00  -  '  + RIGHT('0'  +   cast(MIN(DATEPART(MINUTE,pubpeakhr) + 5) as varchar), 2) + ':00' 
from 
    (select   
         count(pub_cnt) pbcnt,
         CONVERT(CHAR(19), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, dateadd(hh,
         CASE WHEN 
             time >= '3/' + CAST((8-DATEPART(dw,'3/1/' + CAST(YEAR  (time) as varchar)))%7 + 8 as varchar) +  '/' + CAST(YEAR(time) as varchar) + ' 7:00' 
           AND 
             time < '11/' + CAST((8-DATEPART(dw,'11/1/' + CAST(YEAR(time) as varchar)))%7 + 1 as varchar) +  '/' + CAST(YEAR(time) as varchar) + ' 6:00' 
         THEN -4 ELSE -5 END, time) , 121),121 ) as pubpeakhr
    from 
        tblpub ev   
    INNER JOIN 
        tblver v ON ev.id= v.id
    Where 
        1=1 and  v.time>= '2016-05-01'     
    group by  
        v.time) aa
where  
    1=1
    and (pubpeakhr) >= '2017-03-07 10:00:00'
    and (pubpeakhr) <= '2017-03-07 10:59:59' 
group by  
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, pubpeakhr) / 5)   
order by 2
```

Output Of the Inner Query will be like this,

[image]

Output:

[image: Output of the query in an Excel sheet]

Please help me in framing sql to get the desired ouput for Column 2..

Note : column1 (County) is correct.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to find a title that describes the actual problem.

Comment: there is no excel sheet and no desired output in your post. show the details

Comment: Unable to access the output excel sheet.

Comment: @Rajesh Bhat :  I have edited and uploaded the pic again

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to do Date/Time comparisons... This is always going to be hard and error prone. Either use a CTE to build your time periods then join from there or have a look at a Calendar or Time table: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/time-slots-an-essential-extension-to-calendar-tables/ I would not let this through code review, it is very hard to read and reason about

Comment: @MaliniShanmugam Add five minutes to the time varaible for eg.DATEADD(minute,2,GETDATE()) 'Now + 5 Minutes'

Comment: @PRABA : I have tried that .. but no use

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have the input records, I considered your output as a temp table and wrote the logic on top of that. You can also follow the same thing.

```
    create table #tmp1
(
counts int,
timeperiod smalldatetime
)
insert into #tmp1 values (3,'3/7/2017 10:02'),(37,'3/7/2017 10:05'),(2,'3/7/2017 10:06'),(28,'3/7/2017 10:09'),
            (32,'3/7/2017 10:11'),(1,'3/7/2017 10:17'),(31,'3/7/2017 10:20'),(22,'3/7/2017 10:23'),(22,'3/7/2017 10:24'),
            (44,'3/7/2017 10:26'),(2,'3/7/2017 10:31')
;with CTE as 
(select left(RIGHT(T1.timeperiod,7),2) + ':' + 
       IIF(LEN(cast((row_number() over (order by timeperiod)-1) * 5 as varchar(2)))=1, 
           '0'+cast((row_number() over (order by timeperiod)-1) * 5 as varchar(2)),
            cast((row_number() over (order by timeperiod)-1) * 5 as varchar(2))
           ) starttime, 
       left(RIGHT(T1.timeperiod,7),2)+':'+ 
       IIF(LEN(cast((row_number() over (order by timeperiod)) * 5 as varchar(2)))=1, 
           '0'+cast((row_number() over (order by timeperiod)) * 5 as varchar(2)),
            cast((row_number() over (order by timeperiod)) * 5 as varchar(2))
           ) endtime 
from  #tmp1 T1
)
select sum(T.counts) counts, starttime +  '- ' + endtime peakhour 
from CTE C inner join  #tmp1 T on T.timeperiod > cast(left(timeperiod,11)+' ' +C.starttime as smalldatetime) and 
T.timeperiod <= cast(left(timeperiod,11)+' ' +C.endtime as smalldatetime)
group by starttime +  '- ' + endtime

drop table #tmp1
```

Comment: Am not clear what you have edited. Do you mean now you are getting output till 1st table only (output of inner query)? not the 2nd table?

Comment: yep correct.. I am getting the output as desired for the inner query.

Comment: @Malini, I have edited my answer as per your recent changes in the question. Now have considered your inner query output as my temp table data.

Comment: hey, I am out of office today.. I will run d query tomorrow and will let u know.. hope it will work for me ... thanks